# Codificación de entero a decimal

Tags: python, micropython

Estoy trabajando con un microcontrolador y por lo tanto en `micropython` y hay un momento en el que necesito enviar un valor entero al servidor. Por lo que debo convertir este entero a bytes en hexadecimal.

Hasta ahora yo usaba el módulo `struct` pero en este caso creo que no es la mejor opción, pues este valor puede ser cualquier número y en consecuencia, cualquier longitud de byte.

Ante esta situación he intentando remontarme a los conceptos básicos de `python` y he decidido hacer algo tan sencillo cómo:

```
myInt = 300
myHex = hex(myInt)
print(myHex)
mySendFunction(myHex)
```

(Obviemos como funciona `mySendFunction()` pues si le paso los valores bien, funciona perfecto)

Aquí viene mi problema, el `print` saca perfectamente el valor que yo querría, `0x12c` pero luego en mi servidor aparece, `30 78 31 32 63`. ¿Por qué sucede esto? Pienso debe ser un problema de que no estoy codificando los bytes correctamente, pero he probado con `bytes()` y tampoco funciona. ¿Alguien puede orientarme en que debe estar sucediendo?

También he probado lo siguiente, pero nada, da error y ni siquiera se si es una buena opción:

```
import binascii

i = 90
hex_string = hex(i)

binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Por qué no enviarlo como caracteres? Eso lo haría independiente de la endianess de los participantes y soportaría cualquier formato numérico (entero o punto flotante).

Comment: La cosa es que necesito ocupe el mínimo de bytes posibles por temas de ancho de banda limitado

Answer (score 1):

[hex()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) retorna una cadena:

> Convert an integer number to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”

Si usas una página como [esta](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) verás que `30 78 31 32 63` corresponde con la cadena ASCII `0x12c`.

Algo que podrías hacer es ignorar los caracteres `0x` de la cadena que retorna `hex()` y transformar cada caracter a entero con base 16 (hexadecimal) usando [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). Ejemplo usando el intérprete de forma interactiva:

```python
>>> n = 300
>>> h = hex(n)
>>> h
'0x12c'
>>> # Ignorar los primeros 2 caracteres
>>> h = h[2:]
>>> h
'12c'
>>> # Es posible iterar por los caracteres de una cadena con un for
>>> # Aquí se usa para crear una lista
>>> l = [c for c in h]
>>> l
['1', '2', 'c']
>>> # Se puede transformar cada caracter a un int base 16
>>> l = [int(c, 16) for c in l]
>>> l
[1, 2, 12]
```

Todo en una línea sería:

```python
>>> [int(c, 16) for c in hex(300)[2:]]
[1, 2, 12]
```

Aunque usar hexadecimal no necesariamente sea óptimo. Los int en Python tienen la función [to_bytes()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) que permite transformarlos en un arreglo de bytes. Ejemplo:

```python
>>> n = 300
>>> b = n.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
>>> b
b'\x01,'
>>> [c for c in b]
[1, 44]
>>> # 2^8 * 1 + 44 = 300
```